# Escenario GAM para implementar APIs

Tags: genexus

**Genexus 17 u6 .NET**

Estoy creando una API y necesito implementar el siguiente escenario GAM:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En el sistema raíz solo tengo 2 usuarios sistema1 y sistema2, donde cada uno tiene su juego de datos para acceder vía un objeto API.
- En Sistema1 y Sistema2 tengo 2 GAM aplicados cada uno con sus usuarios. Cuando necesito acceder a la api del sistema Raiz quiero loguearme con sistema1 y sistema2 respectivamente.
- No quiero que los usuarios de sistema1 y sistema2 (por ej: s1usr1) estén en sistema raíz.
- Los usuarios de sistema1 y sistema2 (por ej: s1usr1) nunca se enteran que se utiliza el sistema raíz. Es 100% transparente para ellos.

¿Cuál de los escenarios GAM debería usar para lograr esto que planteo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En si, los usuarios s1usr1 deben ser locales de cada App debe estar como LOCAL en cada sistema 1 y 2 respectivamente.

Entiendo que al sistema raíz quien se conecta es el sistema, no es usuario logueado, por eso podes definir en el sistema raíz un usuario sistema1 y le pedis un token haciendo:

```
&GAMOauth20AccessToken = GAMRepository.GetOauthAccessToken()
```

En &GAMOauth20AccessToken obtiene un access_token que puede utilizar luego para llamar a servicios del Sistema raiz.

Lo nativo que se puede utilizar es STS, que es para autenticar aplicaciones usando un IDP común:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43202,Security%20Token%20Service%20Client%20Authorization%20using%20GAM

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias! Esto es lo que buscaba. Al final, lo resolví usando  
HowTo: Develop Secure REST Web Services in GeneXus (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15918,HowTo%3A%20Develop%20Secure%20REST%20Web%20Services%20in%20GeneXus) Pero por lo que veo lo que me mandaste es la forma nativa de resolverlo configurando en ambos GAM (cliente y servidor). Ahorra mucha programación!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la forma de tener este escenario sería usando esto:

[GAM Remote Rest Authentication type (Oauth 2.0)](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?44833,GAM%20Remote%20Rest%20Authentication%20type%20%28Oauth%202.0%29)